# Springboot: Deploying multiple applications on the same server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, web-deployment, executable-jar

What is the best strategy to deploy multiple Springboot applications on the same server.

Should I use different ports for each app? What if I have say 50 apps. Is it OK to use 50 different ports? In this case, if I want a single entry point to the outside world, I should build a controller application in the front to route requests to these 50 apps.

Are there better approaches. I dont to deploy all apps in a single large WAR deployment, at the same time need a better way to route incoming calls using a single end point.

Answer (score 2):

If your server is powerful enough to handle these 50 apps then yes, you can put each one on separate port.

The common approach to expose them to outside world is to put API Gateway in the front of them - either Nginx or Spring Cloud Zuul or Spring Cloud Gateway based application will do the job (depending how sophisticated gateway you need).

Answer (score 1):

Should you use different port for each app? Yes.

One of the reason for you to adopt Spring Boot probably because you want to have a Cloud Native App written on Java. Spring Boot is created to comply the Cloud Native App requirement, with embedded Java app server with parameterizeable listening (or service) ports.

If you are following the best practice of Cloud Native Application, the port should be parameterized through the Java JVM option.

Cloud Native Apps allows the deployer to specify which IP addresses and ports to be used, so answering your question, instead of managing your own incoming call routing, you probably a few steps to adopting the cloud managed app, and late your cloud management system do the routing instead (e.g. Kubernetes).